# CSV file misread with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I just started to learn the pandas library for python and made an excel sheet that I saved as a .csv file.
[The csv file reopened in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJCw8.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')

print(df)
```

Than I read the file with pandas and get the following output.

```
  ;apples;oranges
0        June;3;0
1      Robert;2;3
2        Lily;0;7
3       David;1;2
```

What should I do for the file showing the same way in an excel sheet and a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post your code.
Try this one:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<your file>, sep=';')
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, but now it's there.

Comment: Did my answer above helped?